# Create different dataframe using pandas based on the unique/duplicated with replicating SAS' first and last functionality

Tags: python, pandas, sas, pandas-groupby

Here is the data that create new variables with replicating the `first` and `last` function in python ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46365212/7651845)).

My sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ['D1986','D1986','H1946','H1946','I1978','I1978','S1987','S1987', 'D1974','L1977'], 
                   "ANOTHER_COL1":['DD','DD','HH','HH','II','II','SS','SS','D','L'],
                   "COL_WITH_NaN": ['TT','TT','WW','WW',np.nan,np.nan,'ZZ','ZZ',np.nan, np.nan]})   

    col     ANOTHER_COL1    COL_WITH_NaN
0   D1986   DD              TT
1   D1986   DD              TT
2   H1946   HH              WW
3   H1946   HH              WW
4   I1978   II              NaN
5   I1978   II              NaN
6   S1987   SS              ZZ
7   S1987   SS              ZZ
8   D1974   D               NaN
9   L1977   L               NaN
```

In SAS, I can use `first` and `last` function to get the values `D1974` and `L1977`, which are also unique value.

I want to output 2 dataframes.

Desired output:

```
# df_A
    col     ANOTHER_COL1    COL_WITH_NaN
0   D1986   DD              TT
1   D1986   DD              TT
2   H1946   HH              WW
3   H1946   HH              WW
4   S1987   SS              ZZ
5   S1987   SS              ZZ
6   D1974   D               NaN
7   L1977   L               NaN


# df_B
    col     ANOTHER_COL1    COL_WITH_NaN
0   I1978   II              NaN
1   I1978   II              NaN
```

The above is just the simple example. The complete `SAS` code is:

```
DATA df_A df_B;                                                            
   SET DROP4;                                                                     
   BY ANOTHER_COL1 col DESCENDING COL_WITH_NaN;                                      
   IF FIRST.col AND LAST.col THEN OUTPUT df_A;                         
   ELSE IF COL_WITH_NaN = ' ' THEN OUTPUT df_B;                                 
   ELSE OUTPUT df_A;
RUN;
```

I don think the `ANOTHER_COL1` and `COL_WITH_NaN` are issue. The logic of this is to search unique `col` record and output to `df_A` first, and then if there is any missing in `COL_WITH_NaN` then output to `df_B`. At last, remainings output to `df_A`.

Logic of `first` and `last` function in sas: After group by ANOTHER_COL1, col, COL_WITH_NaN, SAS automatically creates two variables, FIRST. and LAST. Variables in SAS, that are temporary. SAS uses the value of the FIRST. and LAST. Variables to identify the first and last observations in a group.

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Comment: What is `df_A` and `df_B` in this example?

Comment: What is the actual goal (as opposed to the method)?  Are you trying to find values of `col` that are not repeated? Essentially what in SAS you could get by selecting observations where both `first.col` and `last.col` are true?

Comment: Updated the post. In `SAS`, with `first.col` and `last.col`, it can get the records that meet both conditions by group (if applicable). The goal is to get two dataframes.

Comment: So I understand if the first and last rows per group are not null they go to df_A and if either are null they go to df_B?

Comment: After group by `ANOTHER_COL1`, `col`, `COL_WITH_NaN`, SAS automatically creates two variables, FIRST. and LAST. Variables in SAS, that are temporary. SAS uses the value of the FIRST. and LAST. Variables to identify the first and last observations in a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to check if the first and last values in the group are NaN. Then use the mask to create `df_A` and `df_B`:

```
m = df.groupby(['col', "ANOTHER_COL1"])['COL_WITH_NaN'].transform(
    lambda s: True if len(s) == 1 else (
        s.iloc[[0, -1]]  # First and last in group
            .notna().all()  # Both are not NaN
    ))
df_A = df.loc[m, :].reset_index(drop=True)
df_B = df.loc[~m, :].reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df_A`:

```
     col ANOTHER_COL1 COL_WITH_NaN
0  D1986           DD           TT
1  D1986           DD           TT
2  H1946           HH           WW
3  H1946           HH           WW
4  S1987           SS           ZZ
5  S1987           SS           ZZ
6  D1974            D          NaN
7  L1977            L          NaN
```

`df_B`:

```
     col ANOTHER_COL1 COL_WITH_NaN
0  I1978           II          NaN
1  I1978           II          NaN
```

Comment: great solution! Does it consider the logic order in `SAS`? First, search unique col record and output to df_A first. Second, if there is any missing in COL_WITH_NaN then output to df_B. At last, remainings output to df_A.

Comment: I don't quite understand. This puts groups with `NaN` values in one dataframe and everything else in another. Is the logic more complex than this?

Comment: Updated the post to provide full example.

Comment: Let's try that @PeterChen

Comment: Not consider the groups `ANOTHER_COL1`, `col`, `COL_WITH_NaN` as `SAS` did. https://data-flair.training/blogs/variables-in-sas/

Comment: Modify post and got the correct record counts. One thing to mention is above code does not consider `BY` statement in `SAS` which should in the `groupby()`. However, after filling multiple variables in `groupby()`, got the error: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`df.groupby(['ANOTHER_COL1', 'col', 'COL_WITH_NaN')['COL_WITH_NaN'].transform(lambda s:....`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, I think this should work?

```
df_A = df.loc[df.col.str.contains('D1974|L1977', regex=True) == True]
df_B = df.loc[(df.col.str.contains('D1974|L1977', regex=True) == False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you need is to calculate the size of the groups and then filter based on group size:

```
sizes = df.groupby('col').col.transform('size')
df_A = df.loc[sizes == 1]
df_B = df.loc[sizes > 1]

df_A
     col
8  D1974
9  L1977

df_B
     col
0  D1986
1  D1986
2  H1946
3  H1946
4  I1978
5  I1978
6  S1987
7  S1987
```

Comment: Updated the post to provide full example.